# C Binary Tree fork depth and width

Tags: c, tree, fork

I'm learning C and I'm stuck with fork function and processes. I want to create a c program that gets 2 inputs (depth and width) to create the tree like in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNyS5.jpg)

This is the code I have done now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i, depth, width, pid, j, pid2;

  if (argc != 3)
    exit (0);

  depth= atoi (argv[1]);
  width = atoi (argv[2]);

  for (i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
      pid = fork ();
      if (pid < 0)
        {
          printf ("Error");
          exit (1);
        }
          else if (pid == 0)
        {
          for (j = 0; j < depth; j++)
            {
              pid2 = fork ();
              if (pid2 < 0)
                {
                  printf ("Error");
                  exit (1);
                }
                  else if (pid2 == 0)
                {
                  printf ("Child (%d): %d\n", j + 1, getpid ());
                  exit (0);
                }
                  else
                {
                  wait (NULL);
                }
            }
        }
          else
        {
          wait (NULL);
        }
    }

  printf ("Child %d and parent %d\n", getpid (), getppid ());
  sleep (1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does a tree with width 3 or 4 look like?  Or will the width only ever be 2?

Comment: I'd be surprised indeed if you don't have your `wait()` calls in the wrong places.  Let's put it like this — I'm deeply suspicious of them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler IMHO their `wait()` is OK, except they have two of them because they are using two `for` loops instead of just one.

Answer (score -1):

Your post does not really contain a question, so I am going to assume the question is, I try to run my code, why does it fail to produce the expected "tree".  Since you are learning C, I assume you don't want the exact code, but rather, you want to learn "why doesn't it work".

First of all, your picture does not represent a tree of width 2 and depth 3.  Your picture shows only a part of a tree of width 2, not the whole tree, and it is not clear to me that you understand what depth is, either.  Grok this stuff first.

After you understand trees, you are ready to implement one with a single process (forget `fork` for now). For each node of the tree, instead of forking a process, just print something, so you can see that you have all the nodes you expect.

You can't implement a tree with 2 nested loops, one for width, one for depth.  You can use a `for` loop for width, but you have to use recursion for the depth.  The recursive function has depth as a parameter, and when you call it again, you *decrement* the depth.

OK, once you figure that out, then you are ready to add forking. You will notice things will get harder with multiple processes!

Oh, and make sure your code is properly indented. It will help you understand things.

Comment: If whoever voted my answer down can comment and explained why they did so, it may help me improve my answer.  I did not include any C code purposely, and instead provided detailed explanation, to help the poster since they are just learning C. Thank you.

Comment: The 'question' doesn't contain a question, so your 'answer' can't answer the question.  It is an extended comment, and valid advice, but not an answer to the non-question.